# Changing Group Count By Adding Fields in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, sum

New but learning!. Using Crystal Reports for this task
I am trying to do a complicated report but I am breaking it down to some manageable questions piece by piece. I have a table for Work orders. I need to start my report by listing all the different departments with in the Work Order Table whit a count of how many work orders by department .. then for each Department a sub report of the different status of Work Orders and count. It seems simple but i keep on getting a count of 1.

What I have done:
Started a new report
Added in WOCATEGORY (Departments)
     -selected that field and chose the sigma button to
     sum that field
Added a sub report
     - addded in WOCATEGORY
     - added in STATUS
     - chose Select Expert and chose {Status} =
       "Closed"
     - Chose STATUS and selected that field and chose
       the sigma button to sum that field
Added a sub report
     - addded in WOCATEGORY
     - added in STATUS
     - chose Select Expert and chose {Status} =
       "OPEN"
     - Chose STATUS and selected that field and chose
       the sigma button to sum that field

What i end up with is list of all my departments with no count, status of closed with not count and a status of open whit a count of 1?

I need to list all the differet types of Work Orders not just open and closed as well...?
Thanks for you help!

liked are a few photos that might help describe what is above.

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHJY7.png)

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtzEv.png)

Comment: I have moved over to Groups but now i have some issues with totals. This is where I am in the process:
Group 1 Department
   Group 2 Status and Count of WORKORDER.STATUS
-this count is a summary if Status and sum as count
      Group 3 Workorder (Hide Drill-Down ok)

Comment: At this point all is good. The idea is for group 3 to be clicked on and the all the info for Department+ Status is shown, so when it says:
Trash Department
     Closed             102
     Open               38
Click on Closed and the info for the 38 Workorders will then open.
The issue I am having is when I add to Group 3 like Description so that i now looks like..
Group 3 Workorder and Description (Hide Drill-Down ok)

Comment: The Count for Closed and Open change to 98 and 27 respectively. Not relay sure what the step is to make those numbers stick..   the 102 and 38 are the correct numbers based on some other QC reports i have created

Comment: So it seems that I have work orders that have more than one description on them so when I add description to the data to report it counts the the work order every time it comes up , i need to find out a way to count unique Work Order ID's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me with some help..

the insert summary button (Sigma button) and
pick the field as WorkerID
Type as DistinctCount
location = Group 1 (repeat for group 2).
This will insert a summary field into each group footer that you select. You can drag it into the header group header.